# Set the display name of attribute instead of number

Tags: php, yii

I have the User model. It has the field "role" , which contains numbers 1,2,3. 1 - admin, 2 - moderator, 3 - simple user. I've created CRUD controller to manage users. And when I open view.php I want to see "admin" instead of "1" and etc.

When I operate with 2 states I use as bellow. But what about more then?

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
    'status' => array(
    'name' => 'status',
    'value' => ($data->status==0)?"Good":"Bad",
    ),
),
)): ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way is this

```
  <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
  'data'=>$model,
  'attributes'=>array(
      'status' => array(
        'name' => 'status',
        'value' => ($data->status==0)?"Good":"Bad",
      ),
      array(
          'name' => 'your_name'
              'value' => array($this,'yourActionForDescription')
          )


  ),
  )): ?>
```

this means that grid view will search a function in its controller for a function yourActionForDescription()

In controller

```
   public function yourActionForDescription($data,$row){

       $your_value = $data->your_value_column_name;
       //do what you need for retrive your value
       //for eg.

       return $yourSearchedModel->description ;
  }
```

another way is based on  relation